# LARAVEL get result of withErrors in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in controller i'm using:

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
   return Redirect::to('/admin/profile')
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
}
```

how to get result of withErrors in view ?

```
{{ $errors->all() }}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to show all errors in one place you can use

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)

  <div>{{ $error }}</div>

@endforeach
```

If you want to show each field's errors e.g. bellow the field you can use (e.g. for email)

```
{{ $errors->first('email') }}
```

we use first() in order to show only one error each time for each field.