# Laravel 5 not displaying validator errors message after redirection

Tags: laravel

Error messages are not showing.I added the redirection in
  sendFailedLoginResponse it is redirecting to the login page without error messages

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
     return redirect()->route("login")->withErrors([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);

}
```

**Blade**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<input id="email" name="email" class="" type="email" placeholder="Your Email">
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

Comment: How you show the error messages on your login blade file?

Comment: Can you show us your view?

Comment: Also, did you override the `username()` method in your LoginController?

Comment: I edited the page

Comment: What's the output of `dd($this->username());`?

Comment: in your blade you check if error has email index, but you return error with name index, try to replace $this->username() by 'email'

Comment: dd($this->username()) as email index without any message

Comment: Nothing is working. I tried changing  $this->username() to 'email'

Comment: Can you show `dd($errors)` from your blade (or other debug tool)?

Comment: Do you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244442/laravel-get-result-of-witherrors-in-view

Answer (score 1):

return redirect()->route("login")->withErrors(['email' => trans('auth.failed')]);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of array pass a message bag object like this.

```
$errors = new Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
$errors->add('email', trans('auth.failed'));

return redirect()->route("login")->withErrors($errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the input field should be the second argument of the withErrors() function.
[Laravel documentation - Manually Creating Validators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators)

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
     return redirect()->route("login")->withErrors(trans('auth.failed'), 'login');
}
```

**Blade file**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<input id="email" name="email" class="" type="email" placeholder="Your Email">
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->login->first('email') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If Your application is too large folow these steps

While You are making the validation there are several ways

**Method one**

`Using Validator Facade`

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $validator = \Validator::make($input, [
            'post_name' => 'required',
            'post_type' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
                  return redirect()->back()
                                  ->withErrors($validator)
                                  ->withInput($input);
        }    
        Post::create($input);
        return redirect('post.index');
    }
```

**Method Two**

`using $this->validate(); Method`

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'post_name' => 'required',
            'post_type' => 'required',
        ]);

        Post::create($request->all());       
    }
```

**Method Three**

Using the request method

`php artisan make:request PostStoreRequest`

anf the file will be creted in `app\Http\Requests` with name `PostStoreRequest.php`

open you controller and add

`use App\Http\Requests\PostStoreRequest;`

now the file contents

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;


class PostStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'post_name' => 'required',
            'post_type' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Custom message for validation
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'post_name.required' =>'Enter Post Name',
            'post_type.required' =>'Enter Post Type',

        ];
    }

}
```

if You want to customize the error message  use `messages` function

now the store function

```
public function store(PostStoreRequest $request)
    { 

        Post::create($request->all() );
        return redirect()->route('post.index')->with('success','CrmHfcImageGallery Created Successfully');
    }
```

now Comming to the view

to view all the messages add this in top of the blade file

```
@if ($errors->any())
{{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) }}
@endif
```

To view particular message

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('post_name')) has-error @endif">
            {!! Form::label('post_name','Post Name') !!}
            {!! Form::text('post_name',old('post_name'),['placeholder'=>'Enter Post Name ','class' =>'form-control rounded','id' =>'post_name']) !!}
            @if ($errors->has('post_name'))
            <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('post_name') }}</p>
            @endif
         </div>
      </div>
```

Hope it helps